# Laravel Form with multiple select

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following controller, which sends data to a Laravel Blade view:

Controller:

```
public function create()
{
    $schools = School::all()->sortBy('school_type');
    return view('invoices.create')->with([
        'schools' => $schools,
        'dayTypes' => $dayTypes,
    ]);
}
```

In that Laravel blade view there is a form:

```
<form method="GET" action="{{ route('invoices.choose-periods') }}">
    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('school') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
        <label>School</label>
        <select id="school" class="form-control" name="school[]" multiple size="{{ $schools->count() }}" required>
            @foreach ($schools as $school)
                <option value="{{ $school->id }}">{{ $school->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
        @if ($errors->has('school'))
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('school') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right">Submit</button>
</form>
```

As you can see from the HTML, the form is a multi-select form, with the resulting data stored in a `school[]` array.

On submission of the form, I do a test die and dump on `request('school')` and see that for every option I have selected, the value seems to have been logged twice. For example, choosing only one option gives me:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => "15"
  1 => "15"
]
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: the problem doesn't seems related to your blade template

Comment: I agree. Baffled...

Comment: Are you sure you have single selector in your view ?
Others seems fine

Comment: Does your option values contain different values or are they all 15 when you inspect it? And second aren't you just setting all school[] values to 15 somewhere in your code? (Event x)

Comment: @SagarGautam yup - only a single selector!

Comment: @LarsMertens The correct values are being passed through - just duplicated for each one. Not sure what you mean by your second point sorry - Event x ?

Comment: Sorry by event x i mean how the data is stored from clicking an item in the multiple select. Anything special going on in `route('invoices.choose-periods')`? Also check if your blade does not contain name="school[]" twice.

Comment: Offtopic: would recommend to work with Laravel Collective if that's possible https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html. When generating this form you might have no _token on it which can cause security problems in the future.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions @LarsMertens. Nothing special at all in choose-periods, and no the school[] is only in one location. Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I have only worked on laravel 5.7. Try this It is working for me.
Since you are passing 2 objects

```
return view('invoices.create')->with([
    'schools' => $schools,
    'dayTypes' => $dayTypes,
]);
```

It is obvious you will get 2 errors.

In your controller change this

```
public function create()
{
$schools = School::all()->sortBy('school_type');
return view('invoices.create')->with([
    'schools' => $schools,
    'dayTypes' => $dayTypes,
]);
}
```

to this

```
public function create(){
$schools = School::all()->sortBy('school_type');
return view('invoices.create', ['schools' => $schools]),
]);
 }
```

Comment: Cheers. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have not had time to check yet sorry!